# Git: How to add files and subfolders in a gitignore'd folder

Tags: git

Suppose I have a folder

```
application/uploads
```

**EDIT**

```
application/uploads/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}/{g}/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

`{a},{b},{c},{d},{e},{f},{g}` - are hash keys, any alpha-numeric characters are possible

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz - is a hashed filename
```

I don't want git to track it neither on development machines nor on production server, so it is added to a .gitignore file.

Suppose now I've created a branch "Backups" on the production server where I want to store the state of the project at different moments of time.

To do that I need to 'add' and 'commit' all files of a project including those which are under .gitignore

Note: Changing .gitignore is a bad idea in general because

1. It might cause problems when pulling changes from develment branches
2. In a heavily loaded and recently changing project it will be a problem to checkout other branch because of new untracked files that are added each second right after you finished adding and commiting the previous ones
3. etc...

So the question: How do I force git to 'add' files that are under .gitignore ad then 'commit' them without actually changing .gitignore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `git-add` manpage:

```
   -f, --force
       Allow adding otherwise ignored files.
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work I've used `git add --force root/uploads` and `git add --force root/uploads/.`

Comment: `git status` gives `# On branch Backups
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Comment: @Denis: You can't just specify the directories. You need to specify the files to force-add. e.g., `git add -f root/uploads/*`.

Comment: What if `root/uploads` contains only folders (hashes)

Comment: @Denis Then add the files individually, or use `find -type f -exec git add -f "{}" \;`. You cannot add directories to Git, only files. If your `root/uploads` contains only empty folders, you will need to place a `.keep` or some kind of placeholder file in the deepest folder. You cannot add empty folders to git.

Comment: @meagar: Instead of `\;`, use `+`. This runs `git add` far fewer times. (`;` => once per file; `+` => once per as-many-files-as-will-fit-in-the-command-line.)

Answer (score 1):

.gitignore allows not only to ignore but also to re-add, it's the exclamation mark:

```
!add-this-dir/file/whatever
```

You will find this properly documented [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), if you're in shell type **`git help gitignore`**.